# angular 2 - cache http get result

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I have a LanguageService that provides a list of available languages.
This list needs to initialized by a backend request:

```
getAvailableLanguages(): Observable<Language[]> {
    ...
    return this.http.get(ApiResources.LANGUAGE, requestOptions)
            .map(response => this.extractJson(response))
            .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

I would like to avoid requesting the backend each time another service calls `languageService.getAvailableLangauges()`.

What would be a good way to cache the result of the necessary first request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cache it like this:

```javascript
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'

// ...

getAvailableLanguages(): Observable<Language[]> {
  return this._data ? Observable.of(this._data) : this.http.get(ApiResources.LANGUAGE, requestOptions)
          .map(response => this.extractJson(response))
          .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
}
```

Where `this._data` is the cached response, which can be set by `extractJson`:

```javascript
extractJson(res) {
  let json = res.json()
  // something, set this._data ...
  return this._data
}
```

Comment: That simple... Thank you!

Comment: but this won't cache if you do a page refresh

Comment: @FrancisManojFernnado The question was not about it. But if you need it then simple approach is to use sessionStorage. In this case I would abstract http part into separate service which would check storage first and initialize cached `_data` in service. Or make request if cache is not available.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for the reply :) , any article or tutorial about using session Storage in angular2  ?